# Unable to switch off 'faces' option in facebook like box

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I have placed a Facebook 'Like' box on a page and this is now working fine (www.greenlaneecology.co.uk/index.htm ).  Site owner now wants faces removed from box.  I have changed show_faces to false but faces still appear.  Any ideas ?

I now also suspect that the stream and header options are not having any effect either - I think they are just using the default value, regardless of the setting specified.

I also notice that in the code generator for the Like box I can no longer switch it to 'IFRAME'  (or URL or XFBML, actually)

Comment: It's show-faces. You just have an underscore instead of the dash. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sara, are you sure ?  The Facebook developer page for plugins generates an underscore - is it wrong ?    Also, changing it to a hyphen doesn't cure the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply css for now, until you figure out the issue:

```
<style type="text/css">
._43qf{
display: none;
}
</style>
```

I wouldn't suggest using this as a permanent fix, but until you can fix faces, this *should* work.

Comment: oh my bad, I just realized that the stuff you're trying to modify is in an iframe. I'll try something else.